# getting the stack trace from within an Exception class

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to use a custom Exception class and send its stack trace as email when it's raised. But the `__traceback__` property is empty.

```py
class TaskFailure(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args: object) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.send_error_report()

    def send_error_report(self):
        # I want to access the stack trace here
        # to send it as email
        print(self.__traceback__) # None


raise TaskFailure("could not obtain template")
```

Comment: I will ask you here but are you only expecting stack trace for the custom exceptions of yours?

Comment: When you run it, don't you have traceback? I'd guess you do. You're trying to get `__traceback__` value in the initialization, though the traceback only ever exists when you raise the exception, and those are separate moments, from what I understand. This would explain an empty traceback at initialization, but a correct traceback afterwards

Comment: Thats right, I see the traceback in the console but I was trying to access it in the Exception class in order to send it as email. I guess based on comments/answer its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get `__traceback__` value in the initialization, though the traceback only ever exists when you raise the exception and those are different moments. This way, you have an empty traceback at initialization, but a correct traceback after the `raise`.

To see it, you can run:

```py
class TaskFailure(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args: object) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.send_error_report()

    def send_error_report(self):
        print(self.__traceback__)   # None


try:
    # code that might raise TaskFailure goes here
    raise TaskFailure("could not obtain template")
except TaskFailure as e:
    print(e.__traceback__)
    # code to send email
    raise    # if desired
```

Which will print `None` and then `<traceback object at xxx>`, proving the traceback object was bound to the instance after raising the exception. To act on the traceback info, then, you can simply write something to use the traceback info from the `except` block. You can also re-raise the exception afterwards, if desired.

Moreover, if you're interested in the traceback as a string, for printing, you can use `print_tb` from `traceback` module, such as:

```py
from traceback import print_tb

class TaskFailure(Exception):
 ...

try:
    # code that might raise TaskFailure goes here
    raise TaskFailure("could not obtain template")
except TaskFailure as e:
    print_tb(e.__traceback__)
```

You can find more info on the traceback module in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html).

Another important thing is that exception instances are usually not available explicitly. When `raise` is used, it performs a lot of actions 'under the hood' so as to provide a nice halting point for the program (that can be prevented if properly handled by `except`), with traceback, context and more. As we can see in examples from the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions), all 'user-defined' exceptions only use `__init__` method. That makes sense, since we will not manually create an instance of the exception and use it, we'll simply use it as the expression after `raise`. So I'd suggest removing that method from the class altogether. Then, `TaskFailure` would only be left with a initialization that simply calls the parent init, which is unnecessary, so you could remove it:

```py
from traceback import print_tb


def send_error_report(info):
    # send email with info
    pass


class TaskFailure(Exception):
    pass


try:
    # code that might raise TaskFailure goes here
    raise TaskFailure("could not obtain template")
except TaskFailure as e:
    print_tb(e.__traceback__)
    send_error_report("error data")
    # raise
```

Comment: I need to have the exception unhandled to fail my celery task. At least that was the plan. But then actually, I also don't need the trace, I guess. Since I know when I throw the error on purpose. I can just provide more info in the string.

Comment: You could also re-raise it after catching it, no problem. Edited the answer to include that

Comment: Is there a method that gets called when its raised? I understand that with the initialization and that might be problematic in case its initalized first but not raised or raised later. Is the exception aware of when its getting raised?

Comment: I don't think there is. The exception is not a callable to which `raise` applies something to attain a specific behaviour. Instead, `raise` 'warns' the interpreter that there is something fishy there, and then provides context to what's happened. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise), "`raise` evaluates the first expression as the exception object [...]. The type of the exception is the exception instance’s class, the value is the instance itself."

Comment: [Another piece of doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions) that might be interesting, where we have: "_Exceptions are identified by class instances. The except clause is selected depending on the class of the instance: it must reference the class of the instance or a base class thereof_".
There is never an explicit object of the exception class, so it is 'unaware', in a way, it's been raised. However, you could say that when `__context__`, `__cause__` and/or `__traceback__` are automatically set, the Exception 'knows' it is being raised

Comment: Also, about the second thing you mentioned. When we first raise the exception, it is __indeed__ raised. The thing is we just happened to catch it and handle it, but it was raised. Then, later, it is raised again from the same scope, because it was the last active exception. Edited the answer to provide more info on the behavior of exceptions.

Comment: I would assume its not raised if you dont use the raise keyword. `e = Exception("foo")` some time later, `raise e`.

Comment: Yes, if you initialize an Exception object and then use it afterwards to raise an error, you'd be separating both. But what would be the use case for that? Besides making the program harder to read and debug? xD

Comment: What's the use case of raising a exception and catching it on the next line? Can't I just use my code from the exception handler directly in that case? xD

Comment: Yes, you can. User-defined exceptions are an interesting solution to add specific context and info when they are raised. They are more specific than `Exception`, for example. But the code in the answer is just for understanding, it doesn't make much sense to have a `try` block with only `raise MyCustomException("my specific error message")`